# Selenium web scraping error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape reviews from Goodreads. Unfortunately, the biggest part of the reviews are hidden underneath a "Show more" button. I try to work around that using the following code:

```
driver.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36320.Tales_of_the_Cthulhu_Mythos")
page_source = driver.page_source
more_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "Button__labelItem")
print(more_buttons[0:2])
```

[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ca984126647b4165fd01d52f033817dd", element="C87CCF4347B52E1033A6FFABB09491E0_element_356")>]

```
for x in more_buttons:
  if more_buttons[x].is_displayed():
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", more_buttons[x])
      time.sleep(1)
page_source = driver.page_source
```

The error that I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
      1 for x in more_buttons:
----> 2   if more_buttons[x].is_displayed():
      3       driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", more_buttons[x])
      4       time.sleep(1)
      5 page_source = driver.page_source
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement
```

Comment: You can iterate over `range(len(more_buttons))` and use `more_buttons[x]`, or you can iterate over `more_buttons`, where `x` are the elements in it. You can't mix both.

Comment: just use X not more_buttons[x]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly tells, you get this error because you are passing `WebElement` (`x`) instead of an integer to a list.

Should do this way instead:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(more_buttons):
  if more_buttons[i].is_displayed():
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", more_buttons[i])
      time.sleep(1)
page_source = driver.page_source
```